# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI, I need solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I got an error when trying to test my web api url

This is my global.asax:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApi",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Here is my controller:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("test")]
        [HttpPost]
        public PaymentResponseModel Response()
        {
            log.Info("Hello world");

            PaymentResponseModel prm = new PaymentResponseModel();
            prm.info1 = "tes";
            return prm;
        }
     }
```

This is the error message that i got:

```
{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:49484/api/test'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No route providing a controller name was found to match request URI 'http://localhost:49484/api/test'"
}
```

This is my url that i tested:

```
http://localhost:49484/api/test
```

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: How are you testing the endpoint? With Postman? Something else? Are you POSTing to it? Do you understand GET vs POST?

Comment: Does http://localhost:49484/test work?

Comment: @mjwills no it doesnt work, i tested with postman

Comment: I asked many more questions than you answered.

Comment: browsing to the url `http://localhost:49484/api/test` is a GET, you have explicitly said you only accept POST with `[HttpPost]`. Maybe change this to `[HttpGet]`? Though you should read up on the differences as they don't do exactly the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned action in routing. Remove `[Route("test")]`.

Try below code.

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { action = "Response", 
                           id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

If you want to add `route path` on action level use `MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have action in your routeTemplate. You can do this:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "DefaultApi",
       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { action = "Response", 
                       id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
 }
```

and test it like:

```
http://localhost:49484/api/test
```

Or you can also do

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "DefaultApi",
       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
 }
```

and test it like:

```
http://localhost:49484/api/test/Response
```